# How can I use taglib in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, taglib, .a

After downloading taglib (version 1.11.1) from [taglib.org](https://taglib.org), I built it with cmake and got a .dll and a .dll.a file. Then I brought taglib folder to where my Qt project folder is in and named it 'myTaglib' as this picture

[image]

When I go to 'myTaglib' folder, I'll get these items
[image]

Now jumping into .pro file, I tried to link to taglib:

```
QT += quick multimedia core
CONFIG += c++11
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/myTaglib
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/myTaglib
LIBS += -L$$PWD/myTaglib -llibtag
```

And in header file, I included necessary files and `using namespace TagLib` like this:

```
#include <tag.h>
#include <fileref.h>
#include <mpeg/id3v2/id3v2tag.h>
#include <mpeg/mpegfile.h>
#include <mpeg/id3v2/id3v2frame.h>
#include <mpeg/id3v2/id3v2header.h>
#include <mpeg/id3v2/frames/attachedpictureframe.h>
using namespace TagLib;
```

After all, I built my project and got some errors:

```
...
undefined reference to `__imp__ZN6TagLib8FileNameC1EPKc' in player.cpp - line 94
undefined reference to `__imp__ZN6TagLib7FileRefC1ENS_8FileNameEbNS_15AudioProperties9ReadStyleE' in player.cpp - line 94
undefined reference to `__imp__ZNK6TagLib7FileRef3tagEv' in player.cpp - line 95
undefined reference to `__imp__ZNK6TagLib6String10toCWStringEv' in player.cpp - line 97
undefined reference to `__imp__ZNK6TagLib6String10toCWStringEv' in player.cpp - line 96
...
```

Then, I checked these lines but it didn't show something like underlined error or red text or something like that, you can see this picture

[image]

As a newbie in Qt, I'm really confused with these errors. I hope you guys can enlighten my mind and help me deal with this problem. Thank you so much

Comment: Which compiler are you using to compile Qt applications? I think that shared library was built using MinGW/gcc.

Comment: @MariuszZieliński I'm using MinGW to compile my project and I built taglib with MinGW as well.

Answer (score 0):

The actual name of the library is "tag", so you just have to change the lib name.

```
LIBS += -L$$PWD/myTaglib/ -ltag
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work at all. It raised "cannot find -ltag" error

Comment: Could you perhaps try to rebuild the project? I have tested on both Windows and Linux and I could link the lib using -ltag.

Comment: I tried to rebuild my project many times but it didn't work. I don't know whether my project was well-organized or not. Could you tell me more about the way you have tried?
Thanks a lot